# ReactJS - Redirect 404 Error to index.html in Apache Server Windows

Tags: reactjs, apache

I created a simple React app with CRA where there are 3 pages, home, test1 and test2. The navigation is using react-router. The Apache server i'm using is 2.4.55 in Windows.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  // <BrowserRouter>
  <BrowserRouter basename={'/testo'}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter >
  // </React.StrictMode >
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Test1 from './test1';
import Test2 from './test2';
import Home from './home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path='/test1' element={<Test1 />}/>
        <Route path='/test2' element={<Test2 />}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

home.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Home</h1>
            <Link to={'/test1'}>Test1</Link>
            <Link to={'/test2'}>Test2</Link>
        </>
    )
}
export default Home
```

test1.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Test1() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Test1</h1>
            <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
        </>
    )
}
export default Test1
```

test2.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function Test2() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Test2</h1>
            <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
        </>
    )
}
export default Test2
```

in package.json i put:

```
...
"homepage": "http://localhost:80/testo"
...
```

I run **npm run build** and copy all files in build folder to ../htdocs/testo folder then run the server.
It's running fine
[image]

When i click Test1 it routing to test1 just fine.
[image]

But if i refresh the page here, it return 404.

[image]

The CRA docs said that if you want to deploy to Apache server then you need to create .htaccess file and put this code inside:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

I did but it's still return 404 after a refresh. I understand that the server only knows index.html and all the routing is done by React, so I just need to redirect the 404 error to React's index.html. What did I miss / do wrong?